# pandas read dataframe with partial header

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read a file that has partial header i.e. some columns have names some have not. I want to read the file as it is. So I want to keep the names of the columns that already have names and the rest as it is. Is there any clean way to do that in pandas?

Comment: kindly share sample dataset, with expected output

Answer (score 0):

If for example you have missing columns names for column 1,2. you will have this structure after reading the file normally by pandas

```
df.head()
    Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  col3       col4      col5
0    ..            ..
1     ..           ..
```

After reading the df, you can rename the unnamed columns as below

```
df.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 1':'Col1','Unnamed: 2':'Col2'})
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is no, since pandas dataframes cannot have more than one empty column name, so if you try to import a .csv file with multiple empty column names, you won't get the behavior you expect: pandas will fill in empty column names with `Unnamed: 0`, `Unnamed: 1`... and so on (or possibly something else if you have a space in place of the column name in the .csv file).

For example, [this](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv) .csv file with columns of index 0, 3, 4, 5 removed...

```
,Doe,120 jefferson st.,,, 
Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila, PA,09119
"John ""Da Man""",Repici,120 Jefferson St.,Riverside, NJ,08075
Stephen,Tyler,"7452 Terrace ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD, 91234
,Blankman,,SomeTown, SD, 00298
"Joan ""the bone"", Anne",Jet,"9th, at Terrace plc",Desert City,CO,00123
```

...will get imported in the following way:

```
              Unnamed: 0       Doe                 120 jefferson st.   Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4       
0                   Jack  McGinnis                      220 hobo Av.        Phila         PA   9119
1          John "Da Man"    Repici                 120 Jefferson St.    Riverside         NJ   8075
2                Stephen     Tyler  7452 Terrace "At the Plaza" road     SomeTown         SD  91234
3                    NaN  Blankman                               NaN     SomeTown         SD    298
4  Joan "the bone", Anne       Jet               9th, at Terrace plc  Desert City         CO    123
```